# How can I get the Root mean squared of a temporaldata per time?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want a plot of the rms of a temporal plot per time, eg for

`{1,2,3,4,5}`

it should be

`{1,Sqrt[5/2],Sqrt[14/3]...}`

How can I do this?

Comment: Just leaving this for posterity: `Rest[FoldList[Norm[{##}] &, data]]/Sqrt[Range[Length[data]]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by applying `RootMeanSquare` to a slice of the original array up to data point `i`:

```
data = Range[5];
Table[RootMeanSquare[data[[1 ;; i]]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]
```

$\left\{1,\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{14}{3}},\sqrt{\frac{15}{2}},\sqrt{1
   1}\right\}$

Answer (score 4):

A faster way than Felix's answer is to implement it yourself using `Accumulate`, which is very easy:

```
f[data_] := Sqrt[Accumulate[data^2]/Range[Length[data]]];
```

For a data vector of real numbers of length $10^5$ my computer takes 7 seconds to run Felix's code and 0.068 seconds to run mine.